# User claims not to be able to accept an answer, is this really true?

Tags: support, accepted-answer

As far as I was aware there was no rep limit on being able to accept answers to questions. Is this understanding wrong?

I answered [How to delete extra worksheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8092196/how-to-delete-extra-worksheet-in-excel-using-javascript-activex/8092702#comment9920879_8092702) and the OP (who I note has a 0% accept rate) says in a comment that it solved their problem but they can't accept the answer because they don't have enough rep.

Are they just taking the wotsits? If there is no rep limit on accepting then I can't understand what the downside would be to them in accepting my answer.

Comment: Your leg, feel the tug

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nonsense. They can always accept an answer, regardless of how much rep.

However, for low rep users, there is a time delay before they are allowed to accept (15 minutes if memory serves).

Take a look at the [accepting an answer `faq`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought. The timestamping obscures the details but there was definitely more than 15 minutes passed during the comments discussion on that question.

Comment: @Vicky: hover your mouse over any timestamp anywhere on the stackexchange sites, and you'll see the complete time.

Comment: @Mat: Ah - thanks for that! Yep, over an hour after I answered from the time the OP said they couldn't accept my answer. Oh well.